How to pass dynamic variable from server to UI?
I have a small application in shiny:
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
#htmlOutput("d"),
tags$p(id = 'g', class =  'newClass',  'This is a paragraph'),tags$p(id = "demo"),
tags$script(HTML("var tit = document.getElementById('g');tit.onclick = function (){document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML  = Date()}"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)

This application is using javascript. When the user clicks on the sentence, the date displays. But the date is passed in the UI section itself.
My question is, Can we not pass the variable from server to UI here? For example,
we create Var1 <- Sys.Date() in server section. Now I need to pass Var1 to UI in place of Date(). Is it possible?
I have tried with below approach. But failed. Anyone please help since I do not have much knowledge on Javascript
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$p(id = 'g', class =  'newClass',  'This is a paragraph'),tags$p(id = "demo"),
  tags$script(HTML(
  "var tit = document.getElementById('g');
   var insertion_text = Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('bla',function(message) {return(message)};
   tit.onclick = function (){document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML  = insertion_text}"
  ))

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

observe({
  session$sendCustomMessage(type = 'bla', message =  Sys.Date())
})


}

shinyApp(ui, server)



Welcome to SO.  No, you can't pass a variable from the server to the ui*.  But you can create the ui in the server, using render_ui and having a corresponding call to uiOutput in the ui.  In that way, the "ui" has access to the server variable it needs. [ * : if you use a module, you can effectively do that, but in this case that would be overkill, IMHO.]

It is possible to pass dynamic variable from server to UI.
With shinyjs::runjs()
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$p(id = 'g', class =  'newClass',  'This is a paragraph'),
  tags$p(id = "demo"),
  tags$script(HTML("var tit = document.getElementById('g');tit.onclick = function (){document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML  = Date()}")),
  actionButton("btn",
               "data from server"
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    if (!(is.null(input$btn)) &&   input$btn >0 ) {
      runjs("document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML  = 'hello from server'")
    }
    
    
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

With R session$sendCustomMessage() and js Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler()
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script('Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("bla",
        function(message) {
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML  = message
        }
      );
   ')
  ),
  tags$p(id = 'g', class =  'newClass',  'This is a paragraph'),
  tags$p(id = "demo"),
  tags$script(HTML("var tit = document.getElementById('g');tit.onclick = function (){document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML  = Date()}")),
  actionButton("btn",
               "data from server"
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    if (!(is.null(input$btn)) &&   input$btn >0 ) {
      session$sendCustomMessage(type = 'bla',
                                message =  'hello from server')
    }
    
    
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


Read also

https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/build/communicating-with-js
https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/build/js-events/ in particular the need in some case of $(document).on('shiny:connected', function(event) { ... }); when the page is partially loaded but Shiny not yet.

edited after comment
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script('Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("bla",
        function(message) {
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML  = message
        }
      );
   ')
  ),
  tags$p(id = 'g', class =  'newClass',  'This is a paragraph'),
  tags$p(id = "demo"),
  tags$script(HTML("var tit = document.getElementById('g');tit.onclick = function (){
                   Shiny.setInputValue('myclick', 1);
                   }"))
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$myclick, {

    if (!(is.null(input$myclick)) &&   input$myclick >0 ) {
      session$sendCustomMessage(type = 'bla',
                                message =  'hello from server')
    }
    
    
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


thanks for the time. But I do not need a button here. Just a plain text. Once clicked on it, I need dynamic variable to be displayed

I have tried with different approach (refer my question below) But failed. Can you help here?

part added: "edited after your comment"
